# How to subset certain column and change value of a data table

Tags: r, data.table

say I have a data table like the following:

```
test <- data.table(a1=1:3,b1=2:4,a2=5:7,b2=7:9)
test
#    a1 b1 a2 b2
# 1:  1  2  5  7
# 2:  2  3  6  8
# 3:  3  4  7  9
```

What I want is to replace value which are > 2 to 99, but only for columns start with 'b'. I should get

```
test
#    a1  b1 a2  b2
# 1:  1   2  5  99
# 2:  2  99  6  99
# 3:  3  99  7  99
```

Any fast way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `grep` to get the column names that start with 'b' ('nm1').  Specify the 'nm1' in `.SDcols`, loop through the columns (`.SD`), use `replace` to change the values that are greater than 2 to 99, and assign (`:=`) the output back to the respective columns.

```
nm1 <- grep('^b', names(test), value = TRUE)
test[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          replace(x, x>2, 99)) , .SDcols= nm1]
```

---

A faster option would be to use a `for` loop with `set`.  It would be more efficient as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided.

```
for(j in nm1){
  set(test, i= which(test[[j]] >2), j=j, value=99)
}
```

Comment: Nice. Was trying to do the `set` approach and couldn't figure it out

Comment: I was just learning .SDcols and came across this fresh answer from yesterday. Nice one. + 1:)

Comment: I guess this is the equivalence of `mutate_each(test, funs(., which(. > 2), 99)), matches("^b"))`, right?

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, you are right.  I guess you forgot the `replace`

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I did! So it seems that you need both .SD and .SDcols for mutate_each kinds of work. Is that correct?

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, the `.SDcols` selects the columns, and that columns will be used in the `lapply(.SD, `

Comment: @akrun Cool. Thanks for the confirmation. I am off from teaching duty, and I can invest time to catch up with coding. Thanks for your help. Hope to see you in the chat room some time.

Comment: @jazzurro Nice to talk with you again.  See u soon.